# get value of the cell in the last table row

Tags: jquery, html

How to get the value of cell 1 in the last table row?

```
 <tr><td>1</td><td>Data1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td><td>Data3</td></tr>
```

How to get value `3` using JQuery? It's the last row and the first cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to get last child tr of table using [last-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) and then get first td child using [first-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/).

like this:

```
$('table tr:last-child td:first-child').html();
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/sJGZj/140/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.last()` selector to get last tr and to get first td you can use `.eq(0)` or `.first()` :

```
$('tr:last td:first').html();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mc8nt/)**

Answer (score 3):

Try this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk86A/)**

```
$('tr:last td:first').text()
```

**References** :

- **[: last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)**
- **[: first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)**

*Alternatives* :

- :first-child, :last-child.
- .first(), .last().

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr:last td:eq(0)").text();
```

or

```
$("tr:last td:first").text();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sJGZj/141/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr:last td:first').text();
```

You can even use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to find the descendants or the children of a given element.